# Python - write headers to csv

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, cx-oracle

Currently i am writing query in python which export data from oracle dbo to .csv file. I am not sure how to write headers within file.

```
try:
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user','pass','tns_name')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    print "connected"

    try:
        query = """select * from """ .format(line_name)
        tmp = cursor.execute(query)
        results = tmp.fetchall()
    except:
        pass

except:
    print IOError


filename='{0}.csv'.format(line_name)
csv_file = open(filename,'wb')

if results:
    myFile = csv.writer(csv_file)
    myFile.writerows(results)
else:
    print "null"
csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can ethier do this after executing your query:

```
columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
```

so you get

```
query = """select * from """ .format(line_name)
tmp = cursor.execute(query)
columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
results = tmp.fetchall()
```

and then do:

```
if results:
    myFile = csv.writer(csv_file)
    myFile.writerow(columns)
    myFile.writerows(results)
```

or you can convert result to a dictionary and use [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) witch accepts fieldnames