# Python - Having trouble exporting to .csv from sql query

Tags: python, sql

Using Windows 10/PyCharm/Python 3.6 - am able to click a button on my UI (PySimpleGui), connect to sql and run my query.  I can get the results to pour into a .csv file - but I'm not able to get the headers.  Any help is appreciated!
The button is labeled "GET ALL DATA"

Have tried massaging content from here, in various ways with numerous modifications to the syntax and structure - to no avail:

[Python - write headers to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536873/python-write-headers-to-csv)

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch08s11.html

https://kadler.github.io/2018/01/08/fetching-python-database-cursors-by-column-name.html#

Here's a sample of one button's click event

```
if event =="GET ALL DATA":
    connstring = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xxx;DATABASE=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx'
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [TSCACS]"
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connstring)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(SQLStr)
    with open("F:\TOOLS\Button1Output.csv", 'w',encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
        mywriter = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r')
        for row in cursor:
            mywriter.writerow(row)
```

Nearly every time I run it I get a new error message or simply no headers. The single table I'm querying currently has 56 columns and will likely grow to about 78, so I'd rather not have to hard code them anywhere!

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: normally SQL gives only data without headers - they are not part of data. And DB expects you already know names of columns.

Comment: in links you can see that you can get names from `cursor.description`. Probably this should give names `[d[0] for d in cursor.description]`

Comment: Thank you - I believe that is similar to some things I tried from those links - do you happen to know if it goes just above "for row in cursor"?  I'm not seeing how it actually writes back to the file, and none of my tests have worked yet.
Thanks!

Comment: `headers = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]`, `mywriter.writerow(headers)`.

Comment: Not sure why I'm not getting notified of updates here, so I apologize for my delayed response.  Thank you so much, I'm all set!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get headers from description

```
headers = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]
```

and then you can write them before you write rows

```
with open("F:\TOOLS\Button1Output.csv", 'w',encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    mywriter = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r')

    mywriter.writerow(headers)

    for row in cursor:
        mywriter.writerow(row)
```

---

Probably using `writerows()` (with **s** at the end of name) you could write rows with one line of code

```
    mywriter.writerow(headers)
    mywriter.writerows(cursor)
```